# about hardhat deploying scripts

Tags: localhost, hardhat

npx run scripts/1_deploy-app.js --network hardhat
Watching C:\Users\SAMSON\Desktop\LORD and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor dotfiles.
C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\node_modules\minimatch\dist\cjs\assert-valid-pattern.js:7
throw new TypeError('invalid pattern');
^

TypeError: invalid pattern
at assertValidPattern (C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\node_modules\minimatch\dist\cjs\assert-valid-pattern.js:7:15)
at Object.minimatch (C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\node_modules\minimatch\dist\cjs\index.js:13:54)
at C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\run.js:127:23
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at parseFolder (C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\run.js:113:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SAMSON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\run\run.js:63:12)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)

Node.js v18.17.0

i was expecting it will deploy to contract address